# Cant read object from file

Tags: java, arrays

This is my method to read data in files into array:

```
public ArrayList<Product> readProductsFromFile()
    {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        
        File products_list = new File("/Users/User/Desktop/utar/ooad/Product.txt");
        Scanner products_reader;
        try 
        {
            products_reader = new Scanner(products_list);
            
            while(products_reader.hasNextLine())
            {
                String id = products_reader.nextLine();
                String name = products_reader.nextLine();
                String date = products_reader.nextLine();
                double price = products_reader.nextDouble();
                int quantity = products_reader.nextInt();
                String brand = products_reader.nextLine();
                
                products.add(new Product(id, name, date, price, quantity, brand));
            }
            
            products_reader.close();
        } 
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error : Product file is not found.");
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        return products;
    }
```

This is my text file that this method read data from:

```
MMM001
Rice
11/11/2022
1.0
100
SUNRISE
MMM002
Sugar
11/11/2022
1.0
100
SUGARKING
MMM003
Salt
01/02/2022
2.0
4
SALTKING
```

when i run, the system show

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Admin.readProductsFromFile(Admin.java:162)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

When i change to nextLine() to next(), it works fine. How can i modify my code to use nextLine() with no error.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a trailing newline in your file?

Comment: After you read a token like  `nextDouble` or `nextInt`, you need an extra `readLine` to consume the rest of that line. The same cause as [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/3890632).